# How to modify ImageDataGenerator to work with csv data

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset arranged in subfolders with classes' names. Each folder contains 100 CSV files, each of those files has 4 columns and 80 rows of 32-float numbers.

How can I use ImageDataGenerator to feed my model with this dataset? How to modify it or write a similar class for this case? Is there an equivalent approach to do so?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: It would probably be easier if you write some sort of code to combine all the CSVs into one. Then you can use [`flow_from_dataframe`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe) to load the data in

Comment: Thank you for your response,  the case is that each file represents one sample (just like an image), the whole file is a pattern which needs to be classified.

Comment: So does that mean you want to use your CSV as the input of your model?

Comment: Exactly.. how can I treat these files just like images. if I convert them to image I will loss accuracy as their values are float.

Comment: I think combining all the CSV into one is still valid. You will want to add another column for the label, which you can get from the subfolder names. You will also need to flatten the individual CSVs so that each row in the new CSV file has 320 columns for the input and 1 column for the label. After that, it's simple as loading the data using [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv)